# Delayed view refresh after coming back from view on top of the stack

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have an application with two components: one is a list of elements, and the other is elements details. Both are sharing a service, which is a kind of store of displayed elements (details components modifies given element on the list too). When I go back with navigation button on top of the screen, in action bar, from details component to the list component (after modifying shared data), I can see a little delay with displaying new, changed data on list view. Is there a way to instantly see changed data? Some kind of forcing render or view refresh in the background?

In my real app, the list is loaded as user scrolls list (so, it loads 20 first records and then get next elements in chunks as he scrolls down the view). I don't want to fetch all the data again on going back, and also I want to preserve the view at the same place when he navigated to the details.

Here is NativeScript playground showing the problem: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=foWkYF

Answer (score 0):

Your data (`Array`) is held in a `BehaviorSubject` and when you call `next(...)` it's considered the entire data set is updated therefore your ListView completely reloads the entire list. You could simply update the Object at index, which will immediately update only the particular ListItem instantly.

```
star(id: number): Observable<Element> {
    return this._elements.pipe(
        take(1),
        tap(array => {
            array.some(item => {
                if (item.id === id) {
                    item.starred = !item.starred;
                    return true;
                }
            })
        }),
        switchMap(() => this.takeById$(id))
    );
}
```

**Edit:**

Moreover you are not suppose to place ListView inside ScrollView & StackLayout at least without setting a explicit height to ListView. ListView itself should be sufficient most time as it's has built-in scrollable container.

Comment: Hi Manoj, I tried to implement this like you said, but unfortunately problem looks to persist... I tried to use this snippet (btw, I think you thought about replacing reduce with map - in this form it wont compile) and also removing observables at all - and having plain list in data service - but still it looks like the same - its updated with delay on element list

Comment: I tested it before pasting here. It worked, if you have issues please share Playground sample. I agree it could be simplified but I just wanted to point out the actual issue you were having.

Comment: The Playground above is not same as what I pasted above. I'm not sure why you need array reduce and all, that seems simply complicating to me, after all you need is just to toggle the flag.  My sample code just prevents the mutation on subject and edits the original object.

Comment: Sorry Manoj, but I think you are wrong. Here is playground forked from the original, with your snippet pasted in data-service: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=6i2mjl&v=2. I described it in wrong way, it does compile, but on calling star method (clicking 'change starred flag' button) I am getting 'acc.concat is not a function' in device logs, which makes sense as '(currentElement.starred = !currentElement.starred)' doesn't return anything. Besides, when I run it on iOS device, my initial problem still exists. Please let me know if I did something in other way than you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed it and fixed in comment above - this is original one with proper url. I deleted the comment because I hoped you did not read it already

Comment: I am not sure if I described it properly: I dont meant that flag on details does not update instantly- it does. My problem is that if I go into details of element with id 1, here change the flag (here it updates instantly), then click back button in action bar, go back to the list and here whole list updates on view with the delay

Comment: As I mentioned several times so far, it's just a sample, saying you are suppose to change only the object. I removed reduce now, again this code can even be simplified further. Also your ListView is not reloading entire list anymore with this change. Also you are not suppose to use ListView inside a ScrollView / StackLayout, if you are intended to it should at least have a explicit height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201995/discussion-between-nevaan-and-manoj).